# Google Spreadsheet, Sum if cells contain specific text

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to reduce another cell by 34 if a certain cell equals "home"

I currently have which ignores any cell that isn't more than 0. but I also need to reduce it by another 34 if we played at home:

```
=sumif(D2:D20, ">0")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ndcobzUHScY4egFJ-lsay8FQf4IZ5jXlZdhvKv4mk_w/edit?usp=sharing ____ cell B22 is the cell that I would like to reduce 24 if B21 === "home"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
=sumif(B2:B20, ">0")-(IF(B21="Home", 34,0))
```

Since you are applying this to multiple columns, placing the below formula in cell B22 will cause all columns up to column Z to use the same formula on that row.  It first checks for a value in the header row and does the math accordingly.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B1:Z1),, sumif(B2:B20, ">0")-(IF(B21:Z21="Home", 34,0))))
```

NOTE:
You will have to delete the formulas in cells C22 through the last column.  You can also apply this idea to the other rows.

Comment: Nailed it mate, thank you. The first one is what I was after I do believe

Comment: The second one will fill the entire row using 1 formula.  So no need to keep copying it across each time yo add a column.  They both provide the same end results, but the second makes the file more dynamic and is easier to maintain if you need to make a change.